iOS 18 SwiftUI ScrollView(.horizontal) how to disable vertical scroll, drag, and refresh
I have a ScrollView that looks like this
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(someCollection) { collection in
            CollectionButton(collectionType: collection)
        }
   }
}
.frame(height: 56)

The problem is that when i try to drag it's conent, it's draggable and scrollable vertically. The refresh indicator also appears
This is an iOS 18 only issue. It behaves perfectly on iOS 17.
Tried:
replacing .horizontal to .vertical just to test if maybe it's because the HStack has more height than the ScrollView
Result:
.vertical works properly. no refresh no scrolling horizontally
Tried:
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(someCollection) { collection in
            CollectionButton(collectionType: collection)
        }
   }
   .frame(height: 50)
}
.frame(height: 56)

Result:
did not work i can still drag vertically and the refresh indicator still comes out

What exactly is your question? Please review [ask].

I have the same problem: in ios18 my horizontal scroll view also scrolls vertically.

Did you find any fix, I have same issue @pwb2103 ?

Yeah, much like so many other SwiftUI problems, it was something in a view much higher in the view stack (grand grand parent view?) If you see my answer in my case it was a .refreshable. I suggest testing your view at the very top of your app, confirming it works there (with no parent views to impact it) then working your way down the stack until you find what it breaking it.

Your HStack showing a refresh indicator means you likely have a .refreshable {} somewhere in a parent view of the code you have shown. Remove that or move it to the appropriate VStack that you actually want to be refreshable and ScrollView(.horizontal) should work as expected again

this worked for me. thanks
